# Pushkit voip push notifications are not being received on iOS8.0.2

Tags: ios, iphone, push, voip

I implemented new **pushkit** **voip push** notifications and until now it has been working properly in all iOS8 devices I tested except one. 
I ve got an iPhone **iOS 8.0.2** which is not receiving any voip push.
It registers correctly as I get the pushRegistry:didUpdatePushCredentials: forType: delegate called
I tested previous remote pushes (registerForRemoteNotifications) with success but none of sent **voip push** are received.

So my questions are:

*Anyone has experienced same behavior for **pushkit** **voip push** notifications?

*Could it be something related with iOS version (**iOS 8.0.2**)?

*Could anyone having this version (**iOS 8.0.2**), implement**pushkit** **voip push** and try to receive a **voip push** notification in order to discard version problem?

If you need to implement **pushkit** **voip push** notifications you can check my answer on [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245808/implement-pushkit-and-test-in-development-behavior)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only works on iOS8. With this SDK only works on iOS 8.1 (as of writing this it's beta 1). The reason for this is that in 8.0 the compiler linked is a dynlib and is not able to locate push kit framework for 32bits when running on 64bit hardware. But for now you need to compile for armv7 and armv7s.

Comment: [Tanuj](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4627750/tanuj) Can you clarify iOS8.1 is on beta 1? iOS 8.2 has already been released and iOS 8.3 is already on beta 4.

Comment: I do not understand, because I m'able to register correctly to pushkit notifications and even I'm receiving pushRegistry:didUpdatePushCredentials:forType: pushkit function called. Wouldn't it be impossible in case I cannot reach framework?

Comment: What version are you mean? 8.1 beta1?

Comment: Currently the support for iOS8 VoIP Push is still experimental as there seams to be a bug in the new PushKit Framework. For iOS 8.1 and onwards they have released beta 1 version for PushKit Framework.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer Tanuj, but how do you know all that? I ve already raised the question on apple developer support but currently I m not able to find any official documentation about that.

Comment: thanks, i had used this framework in my last project and done some R&D. Accept my answer if it is useful for you :)

Comment: :) probably I will finish accepting your answer. But still I do not understand how I can execute pushkit framework code when iOS 8.0.2 is not able to locate pushkit framework for 32bits when running on 64bit hardware. How can I get voip push credentials but no push notifications?

Comment: Please do the needful. Apple looking into this issue and sooner fix this for 64bit hardware. I'll update you accordingly.

Comment: Ok, apple support answered: "There was an issue in iOS 8.0.x where only sandbox pushes would work with PushKit. Production environment push notifications would be ignored.
Please try your app on iOS 8.1 or later." With no more details... XD You get the answer Tanuj! Thanks!

Comment: HI I am trying to implement PushKit in my app.But My project deployment target must be 6.1 Because of other framework. Now If i implement Pushkit will it work?.Please help me

Answer (score -1):

You have to configure the Voip Push on the server-side, its not just about implementing it to the code.