# VoIP push notification that opens app automatically even if app is not running in background is it possible in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, push-notification, background-service

I want to know that if my app is not running in background and push notification arrives then my app will automatically start.
It is kind of emergency message that arrive and open my app even if app is not running in background.

Comment: You cannot enter foreground from background just like that. When you send the VoIP-push the app will go into background, from here you can make a local notification, from here the user has to open this notification to enter foreground. This is how Skype, Whatsapp, etc has to do it as well with their VoIP-apps.

Comment: Tho you can play sounds and make vibration from the background, so the local notification is easier to notice.

Answer (score 4):

Please refer this link, it is working for me

[Implement PushKit and test in development behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245808/implement-pushkit-and-test-in-development-behavior)

This link contains all  steps to create VoIP notification and please note that this will work on ios 8 and above.

:)

Answer (score 1):

If the app is NOT RUNNING, this is not possible without user intervention.

Comment: I believe that this is the correct answer. I've not answered since I don't have authoritative proof. But my reading of the Apple SDK's says that the desired behavior is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand a question.
If you want to handle when notification reaches your app insert this method to appdelegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary *)userInfo {
//notification reached. open app or do something
}
```

Comment: Hi nuridin thanks for reply but this is what we are normally doing with push notification here is different senario means my app is not in background and I receive notification it will immediately open my app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible. You should use PushKit Voip Push notification and CallKit together. When notification came to device, you can show the IOS default call screen. Then when user answer the call, open your uicontrollerview.

Answer (score -1):

I also want to implement same thing and I searched for this question and I got to know that this kind of facility is available in ios8 and allow us to use pushkit.frame work to do this. Below link is I found some what useful plz refer it and I also referring the same but I m not sure about the result ;)

https://zeropush.com/?_e_pi_=7%2CPAGE_ID10%2C9006801538

more links to refer

http://pierremarcairoldi.com/ios-8-voip-notifications/

https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html&ei=hhTcg8du&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=559&ts=1445159916&sig=APONPFkLqEFK7BggDD1Yz9etBXBkWFLVew

Comment: Thanks Sara I will going through this given link.

Comment: Hi as zeropush was shutdown do you find any alternative ?