# PushKit not receiving notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, voip, pushkit

I've followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245808/implement-pushkit-and-test-in-development-behavior) to implement VoIP push notifications, however I don't seem to be receiving any sort of notifications.

I've tried both with `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195` and `ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195` and I get the message `'Message successfully delivered'` in both cases, however `pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:forType:` is never executed.

I've added a simple background color change as well as a UIAlertController to be shown, yet still nothing.

---

Any idea how I could debug the cause of this problem?

Comment: Is your question missing a link to a thread?

Comment: @JoeCastro oh yes, thank you. Updated.

Comment: Did you solve this???

Comment: Nopem sadly I didn't

Comment: usually problems like these are b/c of a certificate misconfiguration.. have you checked [this](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios8-apps-and-pushkit/) tutorial? what i would do if i were you is test and make sure i got the regular push notifications working first.. then go to vOIP.. [this old school tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) helped me out a lot

Comment: Yeah, I used those 2 tutorials. But then I gave up on trying since I no longer needed it.