# VOIP about incoming call iOS

Tags: ios, voip

I tried to use local notification if there is a incoming call when my app was in background mode. After sending notification, Xcode shows

> ERROR:    [0x1a11f9000] >aurioc> 807: failed: '!pla' (enable 2, outf< 2 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, non-inter>) Failed to initialize graph ('!pla').

If I continue to click this notification, my app would be restart. I don't know whether problem happened in this progress from background to foreground or in setting VOIP.

Comment: I don't have working experience in VOIP. To receive incoming voip call, apple introduces PUSHKIT Framework, which will handle push notification from server. Just i like to inform, this could be the better option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the good answer for VoIP push kit setting.

[Implement PushKit and test in development behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245808/implement-pushkit-and-test-in-development-behavior)

Please check the answer of **M Penades**.