# Unable to receive VoIP notification using PushKit

Tags: ios, swift, pushkit

I am following [this article](http://pierremarcairoldi.com/ios-8-voip-notifications/) and [M Penades' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245808/implement-pushkit-and-test-in-development-behavior) building VoIP Notification Demo. I am able to register notification using `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` and can get voip token from `didUpdatePushCredentials`.

But when I am using houston simulates sending notification to my device, I can get `1 push notification sent successfully` message from console but no actions or logs on device side. It seems that `didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload` never invoked.

P.S. I am using Xcode 7.3, iPhone 6(iOS 9.3) and iPad Mini(iOS 9.3) for development. Distributed Ad Hoc ipa for installation.

The codes posted here.

```
import UIKit
import PushKit


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
let voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //Enable all notification type. VoIP Notifications don't present a UI but we will use this to show local nofications later
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound] , categories: nil)

    //register the notification settings
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    //output what state the app is in. This will be used to see when the app is started in the background
    NSLog("app launched with state \(application.applicationState.stringValue)")
    return true
}

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    //output to see when we terminate the app
    NSLog("app terminated")
}

}

extension AppDelegate {

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {

    //register for voip notifications
    NSLog("didRegisterUserNotificationSettings called")
    voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = Set([PKPushTypeVoIP])
    voipRegistry.delegate = self;
}
}

extension AppDelegate: PKPushRegistryDelegate {


func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
    NSLog("didUpdatePushCredentials called")

    //print out the VoIP token. We will use this to test the nofications.
    NSLog("voip token: \(credentials.token)")
}

func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {

    NSLog("didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload called")


    let payloadDict = payload.dictionaryPayload["aps"] as? Dictionary<String, String>
    let message = payloadDict?["alert"]

    //present a local notifcation to visually see when we are recieving a VoIP Notification
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == UIApplicationState.Background {
        NSLog("incoming notificaiton from background")

        let localNotification = UILocalNotification();
        localNotification.alertBody = message
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(localNotification);
    }

    else {
        NSLog("incoming notificaiton from frontend")


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in


            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "This is UIAlertController default", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        })
    }

    NSLog("incoming voip notfication: \(payload.dictionaryPayload)")
}

func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didInvalidatePushTokenForType type: String!) {
    NSLog("didInvalidatePushTokenForType called")
    NSLog("token invalidated")
}
} 

extension UIApplicationState {

//help to output a string instead of an enum number
var stringValue : String {
    get {
        switch(self) {
        case .Active:
            return "Active"
        case .Inactive:
            return "Inactive"
        case .Background:
            return "Background"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any idea on how to receive such notification?

Comment: I was having the same issue and when I tried to send a notification with node-apn I got an error message, it seems houston console line tool doesn't display errors for some cases. Also be sure if you are using correct identifier and certificates.

Comment: Did you received your notification on your device finally? Do I need any change on native swift code which I posted above? Thanks.

Comment: In my case I was trying to send notification with a wrong .pem file, so yeah that's been fixed. Also note that device tokens are different for development and distribution, that might also be a problem in your case. Code looks ok if I didn't miss anything.

Comment: Thanks! you saved my life. I changed the server address from `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com` (for development) to `gateway.push.apple.com` (for production, I think for VoIP Push, it is the only option). I got the push message finally.

Comment: Ckeck it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48581495/ios-silent-push-should-update-application-badge-count/48581601#48581601

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I fixed this issue.
There is ok for swift source code, the issue is I mis-send the push request to apple's development server `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com`, actually we should send request to apple's production server `gateway.push.apple.com`.

If you are following [M Penades' procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28562124/5500154), please note that you need modify [Simplepush](http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/SimplePush.zip) script, just replace `ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195` by `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195` at line 20 and try again.

Hope it works for you.