# Voip(Voice over IP) missing in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, voip, pushkit

i am using pushKit in my App but `didUpdatePushCredentials` delegate never called. xcode 9 not having `Voice over IP`

Capabilities --> Background Modes --> Voice over IP

[image]

i am following this link..[implement pushkit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28562124)

certificates generated again but not working.

Comment: My app also uses PushKit and doesn't work anymore if built with Xcode 9 (currently beta 5). I see the push messages arrive in the iOS system console (APSCourier Received message for enabled topic '...' with payload...) but the messages does never reach didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload in my app.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Although, Xcode 9 is announced officially, still there isn't VoIP on the capabilities.

I solved my problem by opening Info.plist as a source code and adding "voip" to UIBackgroundModes manually.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>voip</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, voip capability doesn't exist anymore. Adding this will enable the call to didUpdateCredentials.

Comment: Added in plist but, still not showing in capabilities

Comment: @VineeshTP Although it does not show in the capabilities, it still works.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. I don't understand why they removed the "Voice over IP" option from capabilities without which we cannot receive the token. I thought i was missing something in the code, but adding voip worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

according to Apple forum discussion this is the answer

"In iOS 10, you should be using PushKit for handling push notifications for incoming VoIP calls.  So when you build your app against the iOS 10 SDK, you need to move over to PushKit (which can be supported all the way back to iOS 8, but once you move to iOS 10 our recommendation is to update your minimum deployment target to iOS 9). "

original link of the answer:  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50106

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with the settings and I **only need to enable VOIP** as a background mode.

Open Info.plist as source and add make sure it contains the following:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
     <string>voip</string>
</array>
```

I also needed to enable Push Notifications like this:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Might be this is a bug in Beta version because there is no official announcement or article or anything about redeeming VOIP background mode from XCode 9.

Or possible once you implement **[Callkit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html)** , VOIP background mode automatically considered.

I suggest wait for XCode 9 official version.

**Updated answer**

With XCode 9 and iOS 11, Callkit is being compulsory for VOIP implementation. Background mode ( VOIP ) will be automatically activated once integrating Callkit.

Try to make call from WhatsApp, that call history will be available in native phone call app as well.

**Updated answer -> You are can add background modes support manually**

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>voip</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Comment: do you have any supportive link? @hasya

Comment: Nope, i have just understood this after getting official XCode 9 and iOS 11.