# Pushkit and content-available

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, voip, pushkit

if I'm using pushkit to notifier the phone that a new call has been received, do I have to use content-available tag inside payload? Or not? Because using this, it seems that app is not relaunched always instantaneously sometimes

Answer (score 3):

PushKit notifications do not need any special value in the payload to launch your app in the background. Only remote notifications (supported by the UserNotification framework) require the `content-available` flag to be set to `1`. You can find the payload key guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html).

If you're using PushKit for VoIP services, you must have enabled Background Modes and checked "Voice over IP" in the Capabilities section for your project. It looks like this option is missing in Xcode 9 but others have reported that adding it manually to the Info.plist fixes the issue.

See these links:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/85077
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45060044/5059296

Comment: Sometimes the app is not been relaunched... are there some conditions that can cause app to no start!?

Comment: @LucaBecchetti I originally misread your question, so I've updated my answer.