# PushKit not working in killed state swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, callkit, pushkit

I have implemented Pushkit and callkit in my application. Whatsapp call kinda thing..and it is working completely fine in foreground and background but I am not getting call (full screen notification) in killed state. If anyone can help?

Comment: check this https://github.com/opentok/CallKit

Comment: What type of push implemented from server, voip-push or normal? any priority for push?

Comment: normal push from server, priority i am not sure

Comment: I think i am not handling it in killed state or something missed out

Comment: Verify the following, 
1. pushRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:PKPushTypeVoIP];
2. Use voip_services.cer in server.
3. Background mode as Push notification.

Comment: Refer the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245808/implement-pushkit-and-test-in-development-behavior

Comment: I have implemented all this code exactly same But I have not created VoIP certificate. As I am testing in development mode only.

Comment: issue is only when app is in killed state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174374/discussion-between-rjv-kumar-and-monika-mitruka).

Comment: Whole Pushkit Swift and Objective C code example is given here, kindly refer https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification